# How to get element's clientX and clientY (like a mouse event)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to translate `pageX, pageY` to `clientX, clientY` using DOM API?

I have an element of which I need to find `clientX` and `clientY`. I can easily get `pageX` and `pageY` using jQuery's offset method, but I am interested in getting `clientX` and `clientY`. There are no mouse events involved.

Answer (score 19):

My answer is for the question in the heading which is the reason most of us end up here after googling.

```
var element = document.getElementById(...);
var clientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var clientX = clientRect.left;
var clientY = clientRect.top;
```

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Are these all in the same Viewport coordinate system that mouse events use with clientX?

Answer (score 11):

You can find ClientX , ClientY by this formula

```
  var clientX = pageX- document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
  var clientY = pageY- document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

Below picture shows how page x/y and client x/y are relative to each other

[image: client x/y and page x/y understanding]